# operation specified in binding is not defined for 'Porttype', but it is there, wsdl.. help

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, operations, porttype

this thing is driving me crazy...
Whenever I try to validate it.. it gives me error at

```
<wsdl:operation name="ComposedClassOpt">
```

complete definition is below...

that "The operation specified for the 'Binding' binding is not defined for port type 'ComposedClassPortType'. All operations specified in this binding must be defined in port type 'ComposedClassPortType'."

But the operation is in the PortType

plz thank you.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="compose" targetNamespace="http://composeWsdl/"
 xmlns:wsdl2="http://BookService2/" xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
 xmlns:wsdl1="http://BookService1/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
 xmlns:tns="http://composeWsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:vprop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/varprop" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
 xmlns:xsdcomp="http://ComposedClass/">
 <wsdl:import namespace="http://BookService1/"
  location="/Users/adnan/Documents/workspace/TestBpel/BookService1.wsdl">
 </wsdl:import>
 <wsdl:import namespace="http://ComposedClass/"
  location="/Users/adnan/Documents/workspace/wsdlparse/ComposedClass.xsd">
 </wsdl:import>
 <wsdl:import namespace="http://BookService2/"
  location="/Users/adnan/Documents/workspace/TestBpel/BookService2.wsdl">
 </wsdl:import>
 <wsdl:message name="ComposedClassINMsg">
  <wsdl:part name="ComposedClassINMsgPayload" element="xsdcomp:ComposedClassIN">
  </wsdl:part>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="fault">
  <wsdl:part name="FaultPayload" type="xsd:string">
  </wsdl:part>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="ComposedClassResponseMsg">
  <wsdl:part name="ComposedClassResponseMsgPayload" element="xsdcomp:ComposedClassResponse">
  </wsdl:part>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:portType name="ComposedClassPortType">
  <wsdl:operation name="ComposedClassOpt">
   <wsdl:input name="ComposedClassINMsg" message="tns:ComposedClassINMsg">
   </wsdl:input>
   <wsdl:output name="ComposedClassResponseMsg" message="tns:ComposedClassResponseMsg">
   </wsdl:output>
   <wsdl:fault name="generalFault" message="tns:fault">
   </wsdl:fault>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:portType>
 <wsdl:binding name="Binding" type="tns:ComposedClassPortType">
  <soap:binding style="rpc"
   transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
  <wsdl:operation name="ComposedClassOpt">

   <wsdl:input name="ComposedClassbindIn">
    <soap:body use="literal" />
   </wsdl:input>
   <wsdl:output name="ComposedClassbindOut">
    <soap:body use="literal" />
   </wsdl:output>
   <wsdl:fault name="BindingFault">
   </wsdl:fault>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:binding>
 <wsdl:service name="service">
  <wsdl:port name="BindingPort" binding="tns:Binding">
   <soap:address location="http://localhost:8181/ode/processes/BindingPort" />
  </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
 <plnk:partnerLinkType name="BookServicePLT">
  <plnk:role name="BookServiceRole" portType="tns:ComposedClassPortType">
  </plnk:role>
 </plnk:partnerLinkType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue and looked around for a solution. This is what worked for me.

For the Binding/Operation/[Input, Output] - remove the "name" attributes.

This should fix the issue. Though I'm late in answering this, I hope in future some one might make use of this info and not struggle like I did.

Refer to the point 4 here:
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.text.xml.axis.devel/6085/match=matching+portType

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, I changed the operation messages to include name and it went away:

i.e.

```
  <wsdl:operation name="fetch">
    <wsdl:input message="impl:fetchRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="impl:fetchResponse"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
```

to

```
  <wsdl:operation name="fetch">
    <wsdl:input message="impl:fetchRequest" name="fetchRequest"/>
    <wsdl:output message="impl:fetchResponse" name="fetchResponse" />
  </wsdl:operation>
```

- Fixed XML formatting.

Comment: With Oxygen XML Developer I had to (1) add the name attribute to the portType/operations as above (2) go back to the binding, delete it,  and use then autocomplete to help build the binding and operations again. This allowed Oxygen to pick up the new names, and all was well